# Best way to sort a select statement in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Hello can anyone point me in the right direction here. What is the best way to select results from a tabel but show them in a certain way, see below for preferred sorting.

```
10, 9, 8, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
```

make that into

```
6, 7, 8, 9, 10
```

and show in that order?

I have this so far...

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Chat ORDER BY Time DESC LIMIT 5");
```

Comment: So basically you want: sort desc -> limit to X records -> sort asc :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the numbers are not only 1-10, wrap it in a subquery and reorder back again.

```
SELECT *
FROM
   (
          SELECT *
          FROM Chat 
          ORDER BY `Time` DESC
          LIMIT 5           -- <=== change this to the number of records you want
   ) a
ORDER BY `TIME`
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b23a/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Chat ORDER BY Time ASC LIMIT 5,5");
```

Answer (score 0):

query will be like this

```
$result = mysql_query("select * from (SELECT * FROM Chat ORDER BY Time ASC LIMIT 0,5) order by time desc");
```

it will first take all result in descending order and after that take first 5 rows and make it in ascending order.

Comment: ah thanks but no what I wanted, my example probably wasn't very  clear  I need it the grab the most recent posts of multiple rows but then take that 5 and display upside down or in reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Chat ORDER BY Time ASC LIMIT 5,5");
```

Sort ascending, start at the 6th result, return 5 rows.

Comment: If there are 15 results, your answer would select `5-10` and order that, but that would be wrong because OP wants `10-15`.

Comment: @Jack Yes, I agree. I misunderstood the question. The OP wasn't very clear about that, IMO. I see what user1717236 commented on Yogesh Suthar's answer now. Makes sense.